# Indexing composite object in spring mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, annotations

I have a composite object that I wish to store in mongodb (using spring annotations). The object is as follows:

```
@Document(collection="person")
class Person {

@Id
private String id;

private Address address;

private String name;

}
```

and the composite class Address:

```
@Document
class Address {

@Indexed
private Long countryId;

private String street;

@Indexed
private String city
}
```

I need both country and city to be indexed as part of the person collection. Alas, no index is created for them. Any ideas how to create the index?

I have tried the following which works but is not elegant:

```
@Document(collection="person")
@CompoundIndexes({
    @CompoundIndex(name = "countryId", def = "{'address.countryId': 1}")
})
class Person {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up multiple [secondary indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#secondary-indexes), if you wish. This would be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks. But this is not really helpful. First, all indexes are secondary in mongodb. Secondly, I am looking for a java / spring solution.